# How to sort array of object to descending order in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Array of objects

```
this.sampleArray = [{ID: 176, active: true },
 {ID: 181, active: false },
 {ID: 186, active: true }];
```

How to use Angular TypeScript to order them in descending order.

I am using the following:

```
const result= _.sortBy(_.where(this.sampleArray, 'ID')).reverse();
```

But this is not reliable as the ID order keep on changing from descending to ascending. I am using underscore library

Comment: It looks like you're using a library like lodash or underscore. Please [edit] your question and add the tag if you expect answers to use that library.

Comment: `sampleArray.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj2.ID - obj1.ID);`

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use the simple sort method provided by the javascript.

```
this.sampleArray = [{ID: 176, active: true },
 {ID: 181, active: false },
 {ID: 186, active: true }];

this.sampleArray.sort((a, b) => b.ID - a.ID);
```

Working code:

```js
const arr = [{ID: 176, active: true },
 {ID: 181, active: false },
 {ID: 186, active: true },
 {ID: 183, active: true }];
 
 arr.sort((a, b) => b.ID - a.ID);
 
 console.log(arr)
```